# How to open a VC from custom tableView cell

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, tableview, custom-cell

I've a **tableView** with custom cells.

Cell has **programmatically** created button (added via addSubview) in customCell.swift-file (and here we're working)

How can I make an action for this button which will push another viewController via navigationViewcontroller?

(I know how to create action but do not how to push VC from this function)

Answer (score -1):

Inside the definition of your button which may look like the below, you define a target action.

```
        let editButton = UIButton()
        editButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 35)
        editButton.setTitle("Edit ", forState: .Normal)
        editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        editButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("editButtonPressed"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

then in the editButtonPressed (for this example), do this:

```
func editButtonPressed()
{
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nameOfSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: there is no such function in UITableViewCell